# How to store multiple database column values in a single list in Java

Tags: java, database, list, selenium

I want to compare 2 data base tables using Selenium Java.For that I am trying store values of one table in one list and other tables in another list.Later i want to compare both the lists.but I am unable to store all values of database columns in single List.This is what I tried.

```
public class Employee{

    public void execute_query() throws Exception{
        Class.forName(dbdriver);    
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,DB_UserName,DB_Password);
        query ="select * from Employee;
        stmt = con.createStatement();   
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ArrayList<Employee> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            Employee customer = new Employee(rs.getString("ID"),rs.getString("LastName"),rs.getString("FirstName");
            customerList.add(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting error near

```
Employee customer = new Employee(rs.getString("ID"),rs.getString("LastName"),rs.getString("FirstName"));
```

saying

> The constructor Employee(String,String,String)is undefined.
>   Is there any other way to store all database column values in single list?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the constructor for that sequence of parameters in your Employee class. This will need to be created or you will have to make use of a builder pattern/setters to populate the fields of the class.

Also, the ID field is likely to be an Integer or a Long if it comes from the primary key field in the database rather than a String - but this is just a predication as I cannot see the database you are using nor how the primary key has been configured.

Answer (score 0):

Try rs.rs.getInt("ID") instead of rs.getString("ID")List item

anyway, you can store them in a different way;

```
HashMap<String>,HashMap<String,String>>
//As in [Id,[FName,LName]]
```